# DeployLX show Machine ID

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a series of projects, .NET winForms, that use DeployLX for licensing.  This product relies on MachineID to generate the key.  So the flow is:

-The user installs the product
-The user calls us with the MachineID
-We generate the key using the MachineID
-The user enters it and it validates

The problem is DeployLX doesn't show the Machine ID on their screens.  I developed a custom screen that shows it but it is totally out of the workflow.  Is there any other option available to show the customer the MachineID so we can get it?

Answer (score 0):

When you select the Activate By Code option, DeployLX will show the machine code automatically.

[image]

If you'd like to show the machine code in some other location in your - like an About box, you can reference the [DeployLX.Licensing.v5.MachineProfile.Profile.Hash](http://xheo.com/docs/dlxl/5/html/reference/classref/p_deploylx_licensing_v5_machineprofile_profile.htm) property.